# Calling javascript function to get offset of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom

I have a draggable div of which when you drop it, it gives you its left and top value and if it contains a specific class.

Example:

```
$( "div" ).draggable({ 
    cursor:'move',
    stop: function() {

        if ($(this).hasClass('cool')) {
            var state = "Class cool exists"
        }
        var b = $(this);
        var bl = b.offset().left;
        var bt = b.offset().top;
        console.log("  Left:" + bl + "  Top:" + bt + "  Class:" + state);    


    }});
```

and Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sq4XZ/

Now this works just find but I want to call all those methods in a **seperate function** because in my actual script I have to call that function many times with button clicks, hovers and basically not just with you drop the div.

So what i did was this:

```
function cool(){

        if ($(this).hasClass('cool')) {
            var state = "Class cool exists"
        }
        var b = $(this);
        var bl = b.offset().left;
        var bt = b.offset().top;
        console.log("  Left:" + bl + "  Top:" + bt + "  Class:" + state);    

}

$( "div" ).draggable({ 
    cursor:'move',
    stop: function() {

        cool();


    }});
```

so that every time I need to get those values I would call cool() function.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5bQ4d/

Now if you are a javascript guru you would should know by now that this shouldn't work because of $(this). If I replace $(this) with $('div') works just fine. But when I call cool() it doesn't know which $(this) is.

In my actual page I have many of those divs so when I call cool() I have to pass the div id/name/class of which I am talking about. **So, how can I pass the div name/id/class to the cool() function so that it knows that $(this) means the div I clicked/hovered/dropped from?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [Function#call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
stop: function() {

    cool.call(this);


}});
```

This will force `this` to be the same `this` inside `cool` as it is inside `stop`. http://jsfiddle.net/5bQ4d/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
function cool(ui) {

    if (ui.hasClass('cool')) {
        var state = "Class cool exists"
    }
    var b = ui;
    var bl = b.offset().left;
    var bt = b.offset().top;
    console.log("  Left:" + bl + "  Top:" + bt + "  Class:" + state);    
}

$( "div" ).draggable({
    cursor:'move',
    stop: function(el, ui) {
        cool(ui.helper);
    }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/caf9R/

In documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

> All callbacks (start, stop, drag) receive two arguments: The original
>   browser event and a prepared ui object, view below for a documentation
>   of this object (if you name your second argument 'ui'):
>
> - ui.helper - the jQuery object representing the helper that's being    dragged

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
function cool(element){    
    if ($(element).hasClass('cool')) {
        var state = "Class cool exists"
    }
    var b = $(element),
        bl = b.offset().left,
        bt = b.offset().top;
    console.log("  Left:" + bl + "  Top:" + bt + "  Class:" + state);   
}


$("div").draggable({ 
    cursor:'move',
    stop: function() {
        cool(this);   
}});
```